# Performance impact of having "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, iis-7.5

Is there any performance impact caused by the fact that all WCF SOAP based web-services in my organization has the namespace xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" definition as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="List">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Request">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Branch" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="CIF" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="QueryType" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm asking this question due to the fact that:

1. It is hosted on a remote host.
2. Occasionally, MS-SCOM indicates an extremely slow Deserialization of XML objects received (more than 1 minute!).

RESTFul web-services around the organization do not have the same issue at all, although we are Deserilizing the JSON string into the Object Map quite similar to the XML-Deserialization carried out.

Technology: C# .NET, IIS 7.5, WCF, RESTFul,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried that including the namespace declaration `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` causes data to be fetched from the W3C web site, then have no fear: namespace declarations are never de-referenced in that way.

Comment: Thank you very much! have a great day!